# constrain revert draggable object using pixel in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've seen [this](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement) tutorial & I'm working on a project where I want a draggable object reverted based on maximum pixel borders not based on `<div>` containment. Here is a sample code:

```
  $(function() {
        $( "#myobject" ).draggable({ revert: true, containment: "pixels in here" });
  });
```

How can I do that? Any idea would be helpful. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this way,

```
$( "#myobject" ).draggable({ containment: [x1, y1, x2, y2] });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1636/)